# How to get server information from URL?

Tags: rtsp, mms

mms://58.231.196.73/busanmbc-fm-onair-20120228 is an audio streaming URL. When I input this to a web browser, it plays radio.

The default port of MMS is 1755 and that of RTSP is 554. When I input mms://58.231.196.73:**1755**/busanmbc-fm-onair-20120228 to a web browser, it doesn't work and in case of mms://58.231.196.73:**554**/busanmbc-fm-onair-20120228 it works.

I wonder how a web browser recognizes the RTSP default port as the port of that URL even though it is MMS of which default port is 1755.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? I don't understand your problem

Comment: @Eloims i use delphi. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many well-known protocols have default ports, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). In your case the URL scheme contains the required information to determine the protocol and thus port number.

Update: I can promise you, that there is no port information hidden in the URL you provided, other than the scheme.

From RFC 3986 we know that there is either an explicitly named port:

> The port subcomponent of authority is designated by an optional port
>      number in decimal following the host and delimited from it by a
>      single colon (":") character.

Or a default port derived from the scheme:

> A scheme may define a default port.  For example, the "http" scheme
>      defines a default port of "80"

Comment: i know default ports. the above url is mms but the port is 554 of which is rtsp. so i needed to recognize the protocol. i will check that scheme. thanks a lot.

Comment: If the server runs on a non-default port, you have no chance of determining it. You just have to know it.

Comment: if i use the above url to replay radio of applian.com, it recognizes the url as rtsp automatically and if i use the url to web browser, it recognizes the port number which is 554 automatically and whch is not 1755, the number of mms. the scheme says only mms and i guess that there are more information somewhere. where are those?

Comment: Updated my answer. the new port must be some kind of redirection. Other than that it is impossible to somehow "hide" port information in an URL.